# Limit of concurrent HttpWebRequests

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

Is there a limit to the number of concurrent HttpWebRequests .NET will allow at one time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of an *overall* limit, but there's certainly a limit to the number of concurrent connections to a single host name.

It can be configured in the [`<connectionManagement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc.aspx) element of app.config.

Answer (score 2):

As Jon explained, the limit can be set in config. But you can also change it at runtime by setting the [`ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.connectionlimit.aspx) for a specific `ServicePoint`, or the [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx) static property (will apply to service points created after you set it). The default value is 2 connections per service point ([`DefaultPersistentConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultpersistentconnectionlimit.aspx) constant)