# Does HttpWebRequest's limit of 2 connections per host apply to HttpClient?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient

Does anybody know, with confidence if the (default) rate limit of 2 connections per host applies to System.Net.Http.HttpClient.

Please state the source of your information and whether this limit can be increased like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092206/limit-of-concurrent-httpwebrequests) or whether there is a better/easier way to do it.

Also, is there a limiter implementation? e.g. 40 calls per minute top?

There is a good article on a throttling tactic using Reactive Extensions [here](http://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2009/12/19/throttling-high-frequency-data-feed-using-reactive-extensions-for-net/) but I was wondering if there is a HttpClient way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (see the third paragraph of Remarks), `HttpClient` uses a `HttpWebRequest` by default. And `HttpWebRequest` certainly does have the two concurrent connections per host limitation.

`HttpClient` doesn't say if the `HttpClientHandler` (the default) changes any of the defaults in `HttpWebRequest`. I would suspect not.

If you want to change that, you'll have to create your own [HttpMessageHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and pass a reference to the `HttpClient` constructor.

Comment: Took a quick look at `HttpMessageHandler` but it has no way of setting `MaxConnections`.
I guess `Reflection` would help here...