# Async/Await maximum number of concurrent http requests

Tags: c#, async-await

When Async/Await to make http requests (using `HttpClient` for example), is there any throttling built in by default?

Questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations) imply that an unlimited number of connections will be opened. My app, which performs a batch of http requests in a loop, seems to be stay capped at around 50 TCP connections.

I was initially concerned that I would need to add `SemaphoreSlim` for throttling, but .NET seems to doing this for me. 
Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: There's a limit of 2 connections per server. Are you connecting to the same servers?

Comment: Yes, in this case I'm hitting the same endpoint repeatedly in a bulk-load scenario. I know web browsers traditionally have had this 2 connection limitation, but .NET enforces it as well? How does that work?

Comment: [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10403944/885318).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are limitations on connections in the .Net framework. For example this `ServicePointManager` has `DefaultConnectionLimit` That allows you to limit concurrent operations.

However, I wouldn't recommend using it for throttling. If you need control over your requests you should use `SemaphoreSlim`, specifically with `WaitAsync` as you're in an `async-await` environment and these requests are IO bound (and long).

Using `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` means that you don't block and you wait asynchronously which can't be the case for any other non-`async` throttling mechanism. Also, you don't want to start the operation before you are able to complete it.